# Pre remove event not firing for mongoose schema?

Tags: mongoose, mongoose-schema

This isn't firing! No idea why, would really appreciate help here.

```
 Booking.find({_id: key}).remove(function(err, result){
   if (err) { console.err("ERR", err) }
   else {
     console.log("remove result", result);
   }
 })


 BookingSchema.pre('remove', function (next) {
   console.log("THIS ID", this._id);
   next();
 });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per the [doc](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/middleware.html),

> There is no query hook for `remove()`, only for documents. If you set a `'remove'` hook, it will be fired when you call `myDoc.remove()`, not when you call `MyModel.remove()`.

Then you can use this one

```
Booking.find({_id: key}, function(err, books){
    if (err)
       throw err;
    else {
       books.forEach(function(book){
           book.remove(function(err){
              // the 'remove' pre events are emitted before this book is removed.
           });
       })
    }
});
```

You can get more information from this [discussion](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/1241)

Comment: I thought that was what I was doing with that code above. I query it, then remove the result. That's not the same thing as ` booking.findone(blah, function(err, book){ book.remove() })` ?