# add deleted_at timestamp and id to database in nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I want to add deleted_at timestamp to database while delete API is sent.
 `deletedAt: {type: Date, default: Date.now}`

In Delete API I am calling `model.collection.remove()`
Could anyone suggest how to add timestamp along with the id which is being deleted after the record is deleted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write pre method on your model

```
Schema.pre('remove', function (next) {
    console.log("THIS ID", this._id);
    var currentDate = new Date();
    user.deletedAt= currentDate;
    next();
 });



User.find({_id: key}, function(err, books){
    if (err)
       throw err;
    else {
       books.forEach(function(book){
           book.remove(function(err){
              // the 'remove' pre events are emitted before this book is removed.
           });
       })
    }
});
```

refer [doc](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model-remove) and [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36191228/pre-remove-event-not-firing-for-mongoose-schema)  for more detail